# Excel crash and needs to restart when editing pivot

Tags: vba, excel

The following code adds every Pivot Field into the Pivot Table's Value Field. I want this to happen for my database, but my Excel keeps crashing when I run this. I tried stepping through the code to see where it stops, and it's crashing at `.Orientaton = xlDataField` after adding 29 Pivot Fields in. I tried doing this by hand and I can do it by hand no problem. I manually added 50 of them and no crashes. Any thoughts on why this might be happening?

```
Sub AddAllFieldsValues()
'Update 20141112
    Dim pt As PivotTable
    Dim I As Long
    For Each pt In ActiveSheet.PivotTables
        For I = 1 To pt.PivotFields.Count
            With pt.PivotFields(I)
              If .Orientation = 0 Then .Orientation = xlDataField
            End With
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Figured out the problem: The title of column 29 in the database has 254 characters in it, and that's what causing the program to fail. When I change the title to a smaller one, it runs fine, and when I put that field into the pivot table by hand it works fine... Any thoughts on why this happens?

Edit: The answer that @Andrey Ampilogov shared helped me solve my problem. I just added a row below the original title row and did =left(cell above,100), copy and pasted as values on top of itself to remove formulas and that solved my problems.

Comment: crashes always seem to have something to do with mis-handling objects.  Make sure you reboot and then use the answer below.

Comment: @ashleedawg for the record, `Next` vs `Next i` makes no difference whatsoever ;-)

Comment: I also usually encounter crashes on different machines and different Excel versions. Sometimes adding `DoEvents` or a one-second pause `Application.Wait(Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"))` before the problem line solves the issue. Sometimes - a total rework of the spreadsheet since it may contain internal issues I can't notice (like heavy formatting,  traces of previous experimentation)

Comment: @AndreyAmpilogov I tried this and it doesn't work. I'm really not sure what it is... I'll step through it and everything work absolutely fine right up until I make it go one step further into the 29th iterration of `.Orientation = xlDataField`. Could there be something in my data that is messing with this?

Comment: @Pinlop it's hard to say. Try to debug this issue, add after  `For I = 1 ...` clause a new statement `If I = 29 Then Stop` and via `F8` step into this step. What information is in the `Locals` window? Could you skip it and run `I = 30`? Does it still crash? If yes, try running this file on a different machine / turn off active addins (if any).
If the problem persists I fear there is something with the spreadsheet and the next radical step would be to accurately copy the data (as values preferably) into a fresh spreadsheet and run the macro from a new file.

Comment: @AndreyAmpilogov Yeah I did some exploration and nothing looks different on the 29th than it did for the 28th... The program crashes on the 30th as well and so on... So weird....

Comment: @Pinlop Hm... What if you make two loops? One is `For I = 1 to 28` another is `For I = 29 to pt.PivotFields.Count` ? Or even two `Sub`s: the first one works for `I = 1 to 28` and another for `For I = 29 to pt.PivotFields.Count`.

Comment: @AndreyAmpilogov I actually just figured out what was wrong... But still not sure why this is the case. The title of column 29 in the database has 254 characters in it, and that's what causing the program to fail. When I change the title to a smaller one, it runs fine, and when I put that field into the pivot table by hand it works fine... Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moved our discussion with @Pinlop here since there is a limit on comments' length.

@Pinlop noticed that 29th column has a long title (254 characters). This title is supposed to be in a PivotTable title but instead, Excel crashes.

That's a very good notice since Excel cell value is limited to 255 characters, any symbols beyond will be truncated in the cell: [Excel specifications and limits](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3#ID0EBABAAA=2016,_2013).

One workaround would be to limit column title to less than 254 characters. Another is to convert the Excel file (if it's xls) to a new version (xlsx) which supports more than 255 characters in a cell. I also think there is something in VB Editor which can't handle some limitations. A third workaround would be to rename long columns with a short text, then using VBA assign titles to a  variable. And rename back corresponding PivotTables.

Some more links to study other people's experience with that issue:

https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/903554-pivot-tables-more-than-255-characters.html29th

https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/119563-character-limit-pivot-tables.html

https://excelribbon.tips.net/T011784_Text_Truncated_in_PivotTable.html

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply! I didn't know about the character limit, but it seemed fishy to me. One thing to note, I was in the newest version of excel possible, so I believe your second statement is true where there's something in VB Editor which has limitations. Thanks again!

Comment: Glad it helped!
Please make a note of the solution you have finally used :)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try something like this:

```
Sub AddAllFieldsValues()
'Update 20141112
    Dim pt As PivotTable
    Dim I As Long
    For Each pt In ActiveSheet.PivotTables
        pt.ManualUpdate = True             '<< ##
        For I = 1 To pt.PivotFields.Count
            With pt.PivotFields(I)
              If .Orientation = 0 Then .Orientation = xlDataField
            End With
        Next
        pt.ManualUpdate = False      '<< ##
        DoEvents                     '<< just for good measure
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: This was a really good thought, and I was excited to try it out. But it did not work unfortunately...

Comment: @AndreyAmpilogov I actually just figured out what was wrong... But still not sure why this is the case. The title of column 29 in the database has 254 characters in it, and that's what causing the program to fail. When I change the title to a smaller one, it runs fine, and when I put that field into the pivot table by hand it works fine... Any thoughts?